# Drag n' trop with Commonsware TouchListView

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

I use a Commonsware touchListView to list the content the of the device sdcard, some list item represent a file of a folder.

I would add the option of taking an item "file" and drag item in "folder". It is possible?
Like an interface that provide the current list position while the user drag an item (row)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`TouchListView` does not support this, sorry.